# Computing the Jacobian for the change of variables from cartesian into spherical coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus, determinant, spherical-coordinates, jacobian

> This is the question: [image]

My question is whether the answer is $\rho^2\sin\phi$ or if it is $-\rho^2\sin\phi$ or if it doesn't necessarily matter, and why not.

I found a solution online that set up the determinant in the same way that I set up my determinant, however they got $\rho^2\sin\phi$ instead of $-\rho^2\sin\phi$ (which is what I got).

> This is the solution online:  [image]

But I found another solution online that also set up the determinant the way that I set it up and it got $-\rho^2\sin\phi$ (which is what I got also).

> This  solution is:
>
> [image]

So I just want to know which is the correct answer and why.

> This is my solution:  [image]

Comment: here, the determinant is indeed $-\rho^2\sin\phi$, so the absolute value (needed for integrals) is $\rho^2\sin\phi$. In other sources, you may find the answer given as $\rho^2\sin\phi$, but that's because the matrix has the second and third columns swapped (this introduces a minus sign). One other possibility is that the roles of $\theta,\phi$ are reversed, so $(x,y,z)=(\rho\sin\theta\sin\phi,\rho\sin\theta,\sin\phi,\rho\cos\theta)$. In this case, the Jacobian determinant $\det\frac{\partial(x,y,z)}{\partial(\rho,\theta,\phi)}=\rho^2\sin\theta$. Bottom line is be cautious :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the Jacobian is negative, then it means that the orientation of the region of integration is flipped.

You must take the absolute value always.

Comment: oh okay thank you. So it is incorrect to have the negative?

Comment: Is not incorrect if you know that you are calculating an area or volume, because at the end you take the absolute value. But could be wrong in problems that involves orientation like flux ones

Comment: Got it, thank you. so would it be correct at the end to take the absolute value of $|-\rho^2\sin\phi|$ and say that I'm taking the absolute value to preserve the orientation?

Comment: Yeah, that's it